# Can't modify a string in C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, stack

Trying to learn datastructures, I made this class for a stack. It works just fine with integers but it throws a mysterious error with strings.
The class List is the API for my stack. Its meant to resize automatically when it reaches the limit. The whole code is just for the sake of learning but the error I get doesn't make any sense and it happens somewhere in some assembly code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


class List {
private:
    
    int N = 0;
    string* list = new string[1];
    void resize(int sz) {
        max = sz;
        string* oldlist = list;
        string* list = new string[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            list[i] = oldlist[i];
        }

    }
    int max = 1;
public:
    void push(string str) {
        if (N == max) {
            resize(2 * N);
        }
        cout << max << endl;
        list[N] = str;
        N++;
    }
    void pop() {
        cout << list[--N] << endl;
    }


};
int main()
{

    string in;
    List list;
    while (true) {
        cin >> in;
        if (in == "-") {
            list.pop();
        }
        else {
            list.push(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "mysterious error"?

Comment: When you see an error in assembly code, that's probably some optimized library somewhere. Use the debugger's backtrace to dig back to your code and see what you were doing that finally blew up a few function calls down the stack.

Comment: Side note: beside code it is nice to provide example input.

Comment: Even better to build the input into the code example so it can easily be run over and over with the same set.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/r1M74dbGe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string* list = new string[max];` in the `resize` method defines a new variable named `list` that "[shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)", replaces, the member variable `list`. The member `list` goes unchanged and the local variable `list` goes out of scope at the end of the function, losing all of the work.

To fix: Change

```
string* list = new string[max];
```

to

```
list = new string[max];
```

so that the function will use the member variable.

Don't forget to `delete[] oldlist;` when you're done with it to free up the storage it points at.

Comment: Recommendation: read up on [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!